# How can I get the today's date and time in Meteor?

Tags: datetime, meteor

How can I get the today's date and time like this DD.MM.YYYY and how to do it? in Meteor?

```
Template.getdate.helpers({
  datelist: function(){
    var bugun=date(now);
 return Rezervasyon.find({iadetarihi:bugun});

  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the standard javascript for today's date:

```
var bugun=new Date();
```

To format it and get more fine grained options it's nice to use the momentjs package:

Add this to your meteor project:

```
meteor add momentjs:moment
```

You can then do this instead of the above:

```
var date = new Date()
var begun = moment(date).format("MM.DD.YYYY");
```

Comment: I need get it like this 08.08.2015 and how to do it?